# Is Neo-Vedanta a modern modification of Hinduism?

Tags: history, vedanta, neo-vedanta

According to [this](https://bharatabharati.wordpress.com/2012/02/15/neo-vedanta-the-problem-with-hindu-universalism-frank-gaetano-morales/) article, Neo-Vedanta is a modern interpretation of Hinduism that incorporates Western values. The author says this:

> During this short span of time in the 19th century, the ancient
>   grandeur and beauty of a classical Hinduism that had stood the test of
>   thousands of years came under direct ideological attack. What makes
>   this period especially tragic is that the main apparatus that the
>   British used in their attempts to destroy traditional Hinduism were
>   the British-educated, spiritually co-opted sons and daughters of
>   Hinduism itself. **Seeing traditional Hinduism through the eyes of
>   their British masters, a pandemic wave of 19th-century Anglicized
>   Hindu intellectuals saw it as their solemn duty to “Westernize” and
>   “modernize” traditional Hinduism to make it more palatable to their
>   new European overlords.** One of the phenomena that occurred during
>   this historic period was the fabrication of a new movement known as
>   “neo-Hinduism.” Neo-Hinduism was an artificial religious construct
>   used as a paradigmatic juxtaposition to the legitimate traditional
>   Hinduism that had been the religion and culture of the people for
>   thousands of years. Neo-Hinduism was used as an effective weapon to
>   replace authentic Hinduism with a British-invented version designed to
>   make a subjugated people easier to manage and control.

So, is Neo-Vedanta a modern modification of traditional Hinduism designed to satisfy Western needs?

Comment: Neo-Vedanta is just a term coined by someone and nothing else and not followed by anyone so the question of modification does not arise.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria What would you call those set of beliefs then?

Comment: Which set of beliefs? There is no one in Hinduism who tried to westernize or modernize traditional Hinduism.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Vivekananda tried to do it. He himself admitted that many ancient Hindu rituals, like animal sacrifice, are barbaric.

Comment: Yes, animal sacrifice are barbaric because people didn't knew how to do it. Swami Vivekananda's guru Sri Ramakrishna also mentioned that only certain sacrifices done with proper procedure are good as they are beneficial for that particular animal. People with half knowledge were slaughtering animals so God incarnated in the form of Buddha and stopped the barbarism to a large extent.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Ok, then if that's the justification he used, then that's correct.

Comment: There's no thing called Neo Vedanta and it is just a word coined by westerners. All your questions assume there's a sect called neo Vedanta.

Comment: What @ChinmaySarupria said it correct. There are rules laid out in Sastras how to do certain Sacrifices. If Swami Vivekananda said something about them, then it must be there in some Sastras and It could not be just to entertain western principles.